# API call threw an Exception-Microsoft Cognitive

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am running the Basic Console Sample( C#), I have built the project with no errors. Although new frames/faces are acquired and submitted. There is the following error on the console " API call threw an Exception".
I have already entered the Face API Key to the Program.cs file.

Any idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm that you're referring to the following project?  https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Samples-VideoFrameAnalysis

Comment: Hi @cthrash Yes  that is the  project i am referring to . The are no errors on build.I have regenerated the API Key and pasted in the Program.cs.                                                                                           The exception in more detail is showing the following in the console:                                                       System.Net.Http.HttpRequestExpection:An error occured while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebExcepetion:The remote server returned an error:(407) Proxy Authentication Required.

Comment: The only networking requests from that app should be via the Face client SDK, and that client uses the HttpClient internally.  This suggests there is a configuration issue on your end.  IIUC the proxy settings for the HttpClient are taken from the Internet Explorer Internet settings, at least on Windows. Can you see if ordinary web requests work in IE?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but You need provide face recognition address.
Sample code from MS:

```
FaceServiceClient faceClient = new FaceServiceClient("<subscription key>");
```

should be:

```
FaceServiceClient faceClient = new FaceServiceClient("<subscription key>", "<api root key>");
```

For example apiRoot= "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0"

https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236